# Java method naming conventions; Delegate to parameter names?

Tags: java

In an attempt to write concise method names, would one usually delegate some of the information to the parameter names? That is to say, rather than:

```
public Foos getFoosForBar(int barId);
```

Could we simply use:

```
public Foos getFoos(int barId);
```

I do recognize that the second version could run into issues with overloading with differing params with idential types, e.g.:

```
public Foos getFoos(int barId);
...
public Foos getFoos(int lobsterId);
```

But at the same time, if the method names are too explicit they can get ridiculously long, e.g.:

```
public Foos getFoosForBarWithLobsterAndSteak(int barId, int lobsterId, int steakId);
```

I know there isn't any silver bullet here, so I suppose I'm just asking for opinions.

Comment: `I know there isn't any silver bullet here, so I suppose I'm just asking for opinions.` Please read the Help Center on the types of questions you should ask.

Comment: why do you care abot this ? Look at some of the junit test method names. Maybe you won't find this so bad then - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_testsuite `public void throwsIllegalArgumentExceptionIfIconIsNull() `

Answer (score 3):

Using `int` as a parameter doesn't give any room for overloading, but using parameter types does:

```
public Foos getFoos(Bar bar) { /* use bar.id */ }
public Foos getFoos(Lobster lobster) { /* use lobster.id */ }
public Foos getFoos(TheWorks theWorks) { /* as complex as you like */ }
```

Bundling up many parameters into one object is the parameter object pattern.

There is also the builder pattern which when used might look like:

```
Foo foo = FooBuilder.create()
    .with(bar)
    .with(lobster)
    .with(steak)
    .get();
```

in which the `get()` method uses all the information gathered in the previous calls to make its decision of what to get. This fluent style of programming is easy to use and read.

Code the `with()` methods like this:

```
public FooGetter with(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    return this;
}
```

and the `get()` like this:

```
public Foo get() {
    // decide on your foo given all the fields set (or not) via with() methods
    return someFoo;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too partial towards this answer for my purposes... generally, I'll only have the ID's of bar/lobster/steak. With this solution, I'll have to add an extra step of constructing an extra object every time I want to use it as a param.

Comment: Can you bubble this out through your API and get the caller to pass the object instead of its ID? If not, instead of constructing a Bar just to allow overloading of getFoos(), use different method names like getFoosForBar() - it's effectively the same thing but less code.